# Entity Framework Table Splitting One-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there any way of configuring Entity Framework Table Splitting to give a one-to-many relationship.

Currently I have the following Entity

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BoxNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This has naturally created a single table in my database.

Using my DbContext I can retrieve a list of Records from my database. However all records have an associated BoxNumber. Consider the below list of records:-

```
Id, BoxNumber, Description
1,  12,        Legal Documents
2,  13,        Insurance Documents
3,  12,        Other Legal Stuff
4,  14,        Plans
```

What I want to do is introduce a new Entity, something like the below

```
public class Box
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string BoxNumber { get; set; }
   public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

So currently I can do something like this, which will return me a list of Record objects.

```
dbContext.Records.Where(r => r.BoxNumber == 12);
```

I also want to be able to retrieve a Box by doing `dbContext.Box.Find(12);` and I want this to return to me a List with the relevant documents populated into the Records property.

If I tell EF that a Box exists it will create me a Box table - I do not want this, i want to map the Box class to the same table as the Record class.

So basically i need to map two different objects to a single flat table in the database.

Is this possible using EF.

An alternative approach would be for me to return a list of documents from EF and then manually build my Box class from it before returning it to my front end for usage.

For arguments sake this time, I do not have control of the database structure. It could be re-done so that i have a Box and Record table both related, but this seems a bit pointless as the only information relating to the Box is the BoxNumber.

Comment: can you not use type per hierarchy (TPH) in EF??